# Disable MenuItem based on ObservableCollection empty or not

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I check in Xaml if an `ObservableCollection` bound to an `ItemsSource` of a `MenuItem` is empty or not? Based on that I would like to enable or disable the `MenuItem`.

Whats desired:

```
<MenuItem 
    ItemsSource="{Binding loadables}" 
    Tag="{Binding load}">
    <MenuItem.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
    </MenuItem.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can trigger something when `loadables.Count` is 0

```xml
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding loadables}" Tag="{Binding load}">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding loadables.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```